# Is there a better way to solve this problem of winning and losing probability in sports?

Tags: probability

Question：

A, B, and C students will participate in a badminton competition, and the agreed format is as follows:

Those who have accumulated two losses are eliminated;

Draw lots before the competition to determine the first two contestants, with the other person taking turns;

The winner of each game will play the next game with the vacant player, and the loser will be left in the next game until one player is eliminated(the loser of each game sits out the next game while the person previously sitting out plays the winner of that game);

After one person is eliminated, the remaining two people continue to compete until one person is eliminated and the other person ultimately wins, ending the competition

After drawing lots, Party A and Party B will compete first, while Party C will take turns.

Let's assume that the probability of both sides winning in each game is 1/2

(1) Calculate the probability of winning four consecutive games in A;

(2) Find the probability of needing to play the fifth game;

(3) Find the probability of C winning in the end

The manually drawn tree view is shown as followings:As shown in the following figure, the two letters of each node represent the names of the opponents on both sides of the competition. For example, AB means that both parties in this competition are A and B. The letters and numbers on each branch line indicate that a participant's result in this competition is a loss, and the numbers represent the cumulative number of losses. For example, A1, the loser after this competition is A, with a cumulative loss of one. C2 indicates that the loser in this competition is C, who has lost 2 times and is eliminated.

[image]

After drawing a tree diagram, you can solve each problem, but I personally think that drawing a tree diagram is too cumbersome and time-consuming.

**My requirement is not to use a tree diagram, are there any other good methods to solve this problem?**

Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm not understanding the format.  Is the idea that the loser of each game sits out the next game while the person previously sitting out plays the winner of that game?

Comment: @RobertShore Yes, your understanding is correct.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, the chance $A$ wins four games in a row is $(1/2)^4=1/16$  If $A$ loses any of the first four there will be at least two losses by the time he comes back in and three wins will find a winner.

For the second, the only way four games is enough is if $A$ or $B$ wins four games in a row or if $C$ comes in and wins three in a row.  The probability of this is $1/4$

For the third, note that $A$ and $B$ are in symmetric positions so we can assume $A$ wins the first game, then double $C$s winning probability and split the rest between $A$ and $B$.  You have enough information in the tree you have drawn.  For each leaf that is $C$ count the number of games which gives the probability you follow that path.  You could simplify the tree by noting that if $C$ wins his first game he is in the equivalent position as if one of the others wins the first two-no losses and each of the others has one.  I think incorporating this observation is harder to do accurately than just working out the tree as you did.  The tree shows $C$ has chance $7/32$ if $A$ wins the first game and the same if $N$ wins the first game.  $A$ and $B$ then have $9/32$ chance each to win.

Comment: I don't think so.  To end after four the final winner cannot lose a game, which means the winner of game $2$ must also win games $3$ and $4$.  In your tree all the wins by $C$ have five games except $14$ so those legs have probability $1/32$ and the last has probability $1/16$.  Please clarify what you think is wrong